# MDX iif less than date properties

Tags: date, range, mdx, iif

i´m an mdx starter and have following MDX Statement. I want to calculate a new member which shows me for all date less than for example today as "Backlog" and rest should shown as "Open". Following query works so far but in some date ranges i become "Backlog" instead of "Open" and vice versa. Now Date = 7/26/2016

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Backlog] as 
   iif([11 Time].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].currentmember.properties("Key0") < (StrToMember('[11 Time].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].[Date].&['+Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00")+']')).properties("Key0")
      , "Backlog"
      ,"Open")
```

For Example it shows me for the range 7/3/2016 - 7/9/2016 as "Open" although it should be "Backlog" because it´s less than 7/26/2016.

```
6/26/2015   Backlog
6/27/2015   Backlog
6/28/2015   Backlog
6/29/2015   Backlog
6/30/2015   Backlog
7/1/2015    Backlog
7/2/2015    Backlog
7/3/2015    Open
7/4/2015    Open
7/5/2015    Open
7/6/2015    Open
7/7/2015    Open
7/8/2015    Open
7/9/2015    Open
7/10/2015   Backlog
7/11/2015   Backlog
7/12/2015   Backlog
7/13/2015   Backlog
7/14/2015   Backlog
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a way to try to diagnose what is happening is to add some temporary measures to check that aspects of your code are functioning as you expect:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[currMem] as 
      [11 Time].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].currentmember.properties("Key0") 
MEMBER [Measures].[currMem2] AS
      StrToMember('[11 Time].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].[Date].&['+Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00")+']')).properties("Key0")
```

Now return both these columns into your results to check they are ok.